# unable to fetch the data of uploaded JSON file in database Django

Tags: django, django-models, d3.js, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to create a panel where the user uploads his JSON file and it shows result in a specific manner using the D3.js library but it causing some error here is the code

models.py

```
class JSONFile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User ,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='file')
    files = models.FileField(upload_to='json_files', null=True)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
```

views.py

```
 def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = JSONFileUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            json_data = json.load(form.cleaned_data['files'])
            json_str = json.dumps(json_data)
            return render(request, 'visualization.html', {'json_str': json_str})
    else:
        form = JSONFileUploadForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

and in Visualization.html

```
<h2>Data Visualization</h2>
          <div id="visualization"></div>
          <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
          <script>
            var jsonData = {{ json_str|safe }};
          </script>
```

the file gets uploaded in my media but I am unable to show it in visualization.html

form.py

```
class JSONFileUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = JSONFile
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user', 'uploaded_at']
```

[traceback](https://dpaste.com/DTZQJMVWK)

the file get uploaded in the media folder but when I was thrown to visualization HTML it didn't show anything and When I tried to look on the admin page in JSONfile model It show the above error mentioned shown in the traceback

and in migration.py forder in 0001.py

```
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='JSONFile',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('files', models.FileField(null=True, upload_to='json_files')),
                ('uploaded_at', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, editable=False)),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='file', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
```

Comment: Update question with json file you trying to upload

Comment: here is th link of json file https://support.oneskyapp.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/202761727/example_2.json

Comment: although I don't think file is causing any error

Comment: Update question with your form

Comment: I wanted to check if u r sending user_id in json file.

Comment: Hey, the traceback link is not working. Could you please attach that again? Also, can you show the output of `form.cleaned_data['files']` right before you call it and json.dumps it?

Comment: As per your error, there seems to be a problem with you model. Can you makemigrations and migrate them to the database?

Answer (score 0):

The traceback indicates the error is being raised because of the inconsistency between the database schema and your models. In other words, Django tries to insert values for the **`user`** field where the database doesn't know the same.

#### Solution - 1

The easy solution is to delete your migration file and the data and then regenerate the migration field. This is only recommended if you are not in production and don't care about your existing data.

#### Solution - 2

- remove the following line from your migration file

  ```
  ('user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='file', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
  ```
- Run `python manage.py makemigrations`
- Run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: i already tried solution1 with same error all the time and in Solution 2 then how i will know which file belongs to which user

Comment: Solution 1 *should* work in all situations, if it doesn't, please create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (With provided details, the error can't not be reproduced)